# Is there a visual studio addon that warns if code is violating the IDisposable pattern?

Tags: visual-studio, idisposable

I was wondering if there was an addon that could detect and create a warning (or error) if it detects the creation of an IDisposable object that is never disposed.

I looked through Resharper's docs but didn't see anything that looked like what I was wanting.

edit - To be more specific, I should have said a Local variable that implements IDisposable, but is never Disposed.

For instance, a Pen is created in a paint method, but not disposed with after the drawing is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been turned on and off a few times in FxCop.  Its current state is on again, at least for the version that comes with VS2010.  It generates [CA2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182289.aspx) on this code:

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        var pen = new Pen(Brushes.Black);
    }
```

> Warning   5   CA2000 :
>   Microsoft.Reliability : In method
>   'Form1.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs)', call
>   System.IDisposable.Dispose on object
>   'pen' before all references to it are
>   out of scope.

Beware that the reliability of this warning isn't great, it is a difficult problem to solve.

Comment: That looks close enough for me!

Answer (score 1):

It's incredibly unlikely that a static analysis tool would be capable of showing that an object is or is not ever disposed in an arbitrary program. I believe that this would be effectively equivalent to solving the Halting problem.